# Visual Studio Add-in development - Get directory path within a C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-addins

i'm currently trying to build an add-in which is similar to [VSNewFile](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2010/05/18/vsnewfile-a-visual-studio-addin-to-more-easily-add-new-items-to-a-project.aspx). So it's just a simple extension which provides a faster way  to create new files. The problem with VSNewFile is that it doesn't work for C++ projects and i need it for that. 

Here is my problem: 
I'm unable to retrieve the absolute path of a selected directory. All samples i've found were something like that:
`(string)((ProjectItem)parent).Properties.Item("FullPath").Value;`

While this is working in a C# project it isn't in a C++ project. In an C++ project `selectedItem.Project` and `selectedItem.ProjectItem` are both `null` when i select a directory. 

**Important:** I'm not talking about filters! I mean real directories.  
 

Any help is welcome. I've searched for hours now without success. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help anyone else who got the same problem:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsx/thread/bd738463-ba24-4880-beea-f3ec110d981e

```
// Subscribe to the SVsShellMonitorSelection service somewhere:  
public void mySetupMethod()  
{  
     IVsMonitorSelection monitorSelection = 
     (IVsMonitorSelection)Package.GetGlobalService(
     typeof(SVsShellMonitorSelection));     
     monitorSelection.AdviseSelectionEvents(this, out cookie);    
}  

// This class (as used in AdviseSelection) must implement the IVsSelectionEvents interface  
// To get the folder path use the following  
public int OnSelectionChanged(IVsHierarchy pHierOld, uint itemidOld,   
  IVsMultiItemSelect pMISOld, ISelectionContainer pSCOld,   
  IVsHierarchy pHierNew, uint itemidNew, IVsMultiItemSelect pMISNew, ISelectionContainer pSCNew)  
{  
  string fullPath;  
  // Get the full path
  pHierNew.GetCanonicalName(itemidNew, out fullPath);  

  // Do something with the path...  
  return VSConstants.S_OK;  
}
```